# In Lucene .Net 4.8, need an Analyzer that doesn't splits (delimits) words on dot '.'

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene .Net 4.8 with the following Analyzer:

```
private static Analyzer CreateAnalyzer()
{
    return Analyzer.NewAnonymous(createComponents: (fieldName, reader) =>
    {
        var source = new WhitespaceTokenizer(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, reader);
        TokenStream result = new WordDelimiterFilter(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, source,
            ~WordDelimiterFlags.STEM_ENGLISH_POSSESSIVE,
            CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET);
        result = new LowerCaseFilter(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, result);
        return new TokenStreamComponents(source, result);
    });
}
```

This works great for 95% of my use cases.
For example, for the sentence "Hello MacDonald", all of the following will return a match: 'Hello', 'mac', 'dona".

My problem comes with emails like: "JoshSmith@microsoft.com"

Currently searching for 'Microsoft' or 'com' will return a match. But, since my WordDelimiterFilter stops at '.', searching for "microsoft.com" doesn't return a match.

Optimally, I'd like to index both "microsoft.com" and "com" so searching for both will return a match.
I'm willing to settle for Lucene to treat dot '.' as a regular character and to index "microsoft.com" only.

I tried writing in the last parameter instead of "CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET" the following:

```
new CharArraySet(Lucene.Net.Util.LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, new List<string>() { "." }, true)
```

Didn't help.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using the [UAX29 classes](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/package-summary.html), which are specifically meant to handle email addresses and URLs?